# how to to use MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to insert a middleware class into a GAE based Django (1.3) for logging exceptions. I have tried putting one class name in the project's path but it's not being called.

What is the 'right' way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just place your class in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py`

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ...
  'package.mod.ExceptionLoggingClass',
)

In your `mod.py` type

```
import logging
class ExceptionLoggingClass(object):
   process_exception(request, exception):
     logging.error(exception)
```

If the `process_exception` returns `None` the default behaviour occurs otherwise return your own `HttpResponse`

[Refference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception)